# Snubbing LC oscillation

Tags: mosfet-driver, rfid, oscillation, snubber

I have a series LC resonant circuit L = 44.4mH C = 36.5pF fr = 125kHz.
It is LF RFID antenna.
The LC circuit is powered by an H-bridge with MOSFET transistors.
125kHz carrier frequency, 1kHz modulation frequency (OOK).
The problem is when the key signal goes low. The LC system oscillates for a very long time.
How to extinguish these oscillations very quickly.

[image: Typical H-bridge with IR2104 drivers]

The carrier signal and keying is generated from the processor's PWM module.
[image: PWM]

Could this be the right direction:
[image: Cut off]

regards

Comment: Where is key signal?

Comment: And please share the driving details. If you idle the circuit with a couple of MOS in the bridge  on driven you actually have to wait for natural oscillation damping. What you should do instead is having all the four MOS off. This way you use power rails to clamp free oscillation. An extra, small, snubber can then be used to cope with MOS parasitic capacitance ringing.

Comment: @carloc i dont have problem with MOS parasitic capacitance ringing. When the keying signal is low, the MOSFET's (Q12, Q22) on the low side will short both ends of the LC circuit to GND via a 0.22ohm resistor. Self-extinguishing oscillations are too strong and take too long. I want to put them out immediately. Maybe some additional active circuit?

Comment: "When the keying signal is low, the MOSFET's (Q12, Q22) on the low side will short both ends of the LC circuit to GND via a 0.22ohm resistor" This is exactly what you should try do avoid. Shorting a series resonant circuit leaves it ringing freely. Clamp it instead, open all MOS at the end.

Comment: @carloc ( carloc ) This is it! Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I have to move the keying to the SD input (shutdown). This is not a nice solution, but the driver used does not allow you to control the high and low side separately.